# No AC/Ventilation out of nowhere

Tags: ac, peugeot, peugeot-208

I have a Peugeot 208 1.2 Puretech 82hp, after sitting parked for a few days, the AC just stopped functioning and gives no air at all through the vents.

It's an automatic AC, the display and buttons are perfectly usable but doing any actions doesn't do anything (outside of the back window defrosting which is electric), so I don't think the issue is with the controls.

I tried driving it a bit (up to temp, around 20km), no change.

I checked the accessories belt, which seems to be in good physical shape, the inboard filter is ~6 months old (maybe it is ultra gunked up, I haven't taken a look at it, but that seems weird as it was working perfectly before and nothing except for parking happens), nobody at my knowledge worked on the AC of the car at all.

Short of giving it to a mechanic, what could I have missed to check for a potential cause?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1):

Is the problem no air at all is coming through or no cold air is coming through? From your description, it sounds like the fan isn't blowing air. Usually, this is most often caused from the blower motor resistor going bad. The resistor allows for the fan to run at different speeds. The way it does it is by bleeding off power by creating heat. Because they get so hot, they often go out after so much usage. When they go out, the fan stops blowing.

If you can easily get to your fan motor, you can apply power directly to it by disconnecting the electrical connector and supplying a 12v source. If it blows, you know its not the motor. I doubt it's the blower motor. They usually go bad while making a lot of whining noise. They usually don't just quit working.

Comment: No air at all, indeed. However, I just discovered that anything AC related is included in my car's warranty, so gonna leave it to the dealer to fix for free, thanks for the suggestion though

Comment: @NicolasFormichella - Absolutely ... if it's under warranty don't do anything to it which might void it. Also, when you take it in for the warranty work, don't tell them anything about you might have an inkling about what could be going on.